# Creating very simple book template from scratch

Tags: book-design

I'm trying to implement a simple book template from scratch, where each individual chapter begins like this:

[image]

And the respective table of contents looks like this:

[image]

No matter how hard I try to do something seemingly this simple, I keep running into all sorts of errors.  The minimal working example that I seem to have working properly is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots, alphalph}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}

%--------------Page number top right
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
%--------------


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents


\section{Section 1}
Section 1 text goes here.

\section{Section 2}
Section 2 text goes here.


\end{document}
```

Where I've successfully delimited my subsections properly, yet I'm having a hard time proceeding forward from here.

This is the first time that I'm trying to implement a book template from scratch, usually I use one of the existing ones online.  However, this specific book template seems like something that can be done with relative ease (compared to some of the ones online), particularly because it just has a table of contents and referencing to the specific sections of each chapter.  Can't be that bad, right?  I'm not sure why I'm having such difficulties.

I wish I could show my errors for each thing that I tried, but that would make the size of this post unwieldy.  Instead I've opted to give my desired target (screenshots attached), and the MWE that I so far have gotten working.

Comment: I would recommend using either `memoir` or `scrbook` as the documentclass. Both of those classes have very good documentation on how to adjust everything you would need to make this layout.  If you don't do this, then you will need different packages to do what you want: a good combination is the `titlesec`, `titletoc`, `titileps` suite, although its documentation (although complete) is quite terse.

Comment: @AlanMunn Will follow your advice.  May I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, there's no problem to delete the question. If you get stuck with one of the new classes, you can post a more specific question based on what you've done with them.

Comment: Any news here? From a TeXnical point of view, this isn't simple nd needs quite some effort.